# Docker compose intellisense

Tags: docker, visual-studio-code

When creating `docker-compose.yml` vscode autocomplete/ intellisense doesn't work. Also `ctrl+space` doesn't work. How can I make it work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you have to go back to a previous version of the Docker VSCode extension, such as `v1.16.1` .

From the VSCode developers:

> The functionality present in 1.17 for the language service is fairly limited; we're working on adding back a lot more in 1.18.

[image: how to install other VSCode version]

See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docker/issues/3222